# making simple responsive page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Here I have create simple page, which should be responsive against all size screen. 
I have taken care, but still it appears diff on diff size screen.

Is that any improvment in layout?

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3fpYH/

I have attached snapshot, how I want it to look like and it appears like that only on my screen.

```
<div class="container">

            <div class= "top">
                 <span class = "first-letter3">V</span>UVU<span class="yellow">VA  </span>
            </div>
            <div class= "middle">
                <div class= "second">
                    <span class = "first-letter2"> Y</span>OU'VE FINALLY OPENED UP YOUR DREAM BUSINESS <br/> OR DEVELOPED THAT MOBILE APP YOU'VE BEEN TALKING ABOUT </br></br>
                    BUT THE WORK ISN'T OVER YET. </br></br>
                    VUVU<span class="yellow">VA</span> UTILIZES ADVANCED ADVERTISING <br/> TO DRIVE CUSTOMER TO YOUR SHOP OR DOWNLOAD TO YOUR MOBILE APP. <br><br> WITH US, YOU ONLY NEED TO WORRY ABOUT YOUR BUSINESS </br> INSTEAD IF GETTING BUSINESS. </br></br>

                DO YOU HAVE A BUSINES? | CONTACT US: <span class="yellow">BUSINES@VUVUVA.COM</span> <br/><br/>
                DO YOU HAVE A MOBILE APP? | CONTACT US: <span class="yellow">APP@VUVUVA.COM</span>
                </div>


            </div>

</div>
                <div class = "second bottom">
                    <a href="index.php" class = "yellow"><span class="yellow" style ="float:left"><span class = "first-letter1 yellow">H</span>OME </span></a>
                <span style ="float:right"> <span class = "first-letter1">E</span>ST. MMXIV   </span>
                </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Think of @media queries.

Comment: Appearing different on different screen sizes is the *point* of responsive design!

Comment: Except of your .top container being cut off due to negativ margin, I see no problem?

Comment: Just like Ali Gajani said, use media queries in which you set new font size for different screen size.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example how to change font size in media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .second {        
        font-size: 10px;
    }
} 
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .second {        
        font-size: 8px;
    }
}
```

<kbd>**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3fpYH/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: will the elements position in my page will remain same on all screen?

Comment: bottom line is not that much up, why in fiddle of your example it is appearing so upward?

Comment: Because I've changed only the font size. If you want that line to remain at the bottom, I recommend to use [sticky footer](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/). Or change `.bottom`'s `margin-top` in the media queries.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no problem with your design.
If you want to alter this based on different screen resolutions. You can think about using media query:

Example you can reduce font size for a screen like iphone and keep it high for desktop devices:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
.container{
font-size:10px;
}
}
```

Study the following link for refernce:-

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: will the elements position in my page will remain same on all screen?

Comment: it totally depends upon how/where you want to place them. Generally if there are N components in a row and in devices with smaller widths, they are not rendering properly you would stack them one above other rather then keeping them in-line.